# MAMP, can't conect to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have recently installed MAMP on Windows 10 in order to install WordPress. After installation Apache and MySQL are running very fine. However after rebooting system and even turning MAMP server off and on the only one service running is Apache. When I try connecting to phpMyAdmin i receive an "Access denied" error: 
"MySQL said:
Cannot connect: invalid settings."
Then next popup is: 
"mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002):" then text in polish that says the target pc rejects the connection.

On the bottom last message: 
"phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."
I tried reinstalling, removing mySQL logs, changing active php version, no success.
On MAMP application panel there is green light next to Apache server but empty one next to MySQL.
Edit: after removing all files that are not inside subfolders in /MAMP/db/mysql it started to trun on again. However remocing those files corrupts my WordPress installation so it begins with new installation, and then everything crashes in WP

Comment: Look in the MySQL error logs...

Comment: where can i found them?

Comment: "removing mySQL logs"?

Comment: right xD, the true question is how can i read them while they have no extension, changing it to txt gives blank file